# Is the address of a global variable guaranteed to stay the same during the process execution?

Tags: c, pointers, static, global-variables

Is the address of a global variable guaranteed to say the same during the whole process execution? That is, I have

```
static int dummy;
```

and I use

```
something(&dummy);
```

in a few different places across my code. Will `&dummy` ever change, or can I safely use it as a key that is unlikely to be reused by another library (e.g. in a hashmap)?

This is, of course, assuming I don't restart the program or reload the library.

(Context: This was recommended to me by some people on the Lua mailing list. I've been using it [here](https://github.com/SoniEx2/loadx/blob/master/loadx.c).)

Comment: Yes it does remain same.

Comment: I would hope and pray that the address of even a local var would say the same, once allocated, during the whole process execution, (assuming it is never destroyed).  If they start moving around, all my code base on every project is doomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, C11§6.2.4 states:

> [2] The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
>   guaranteed to be reserved for it. **An object exists, has a constant address, 33) and retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.** 34) If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
>   the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.
>
> [3] An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier static, has static storage duration. **Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program** and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Footnote 33:

> 33) The term ‘‘constant address’’ means that two pointers to the object constructed at possibly different
>   times will compare equal. The address may be different during two different executions of the same
>   program.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  From the C99 spec:

> **[6.2.4]** The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, **has a constant address**, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.